# how to dynamically duplicate specific tablerow

Tags: android, tablerow

i want to create a copy of my tablerow with its elements in it and the same params when a button clicked. is there any way to do this?
my unsuccessful try was this:
xml:

```
<TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/my_row"
        >


        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dalass"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autocompletetextview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text=""
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                 android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                 android:textColor="#000000"
                 >
        </AutoCompleteTextView>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edit_sale2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            />

       </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

java:

```
View.OnClickListener handler_add=new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflator = Sale.this.getLayoutInflater();
                    TableRow rowView = (TableRow) inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_sale, null);
        table_sale.addView(rowView);

    }

};
```

i dont know what the inflater exactly does. somebody help me please :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter of the `LayoutInflater.inflate` method, which you currently have set as `null`, is the root of the layout you want to inflate into. Try this;

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflator = Sale.this.getLayoutInflater();
                TableRow rowView = new TableRow(v.getContext());
                inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_sale, rowView);
    table_sale.addView(rowView);

}
```

You should also edit your xml so that it is merged into the rowView object, to avoid unnecessary additional views.

**`activity_sale.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/my_row" >


    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dalass"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autocompletetextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:textColor="#000000" >

        </AutoCompleteTextView>

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edit_sale2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" />

   </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Comment: thanks, its working now; but it's inflating the whole layout. where i need to inflate just a row of my table layout. is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have assumed that `R.layout.activity_sale` is the name of the xml file which defines the single row to add to your `TableLayout`. Is this not the case?

Comment: No, it was a part of my activity layout, so by adding another xml file which has just the tablerow in it problem solved. thanks a lot